# Desplegar django en servidor linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

estoy intentado desplegar un proyecto django en un servidor linux. Por lo que veo en la web hay muchas manera de desplegarla:
 - Apache + wsgi
 - Nginx + uwsgi
 - Nginx + gunicorn

y seguramente muchas otras que no he visto. ¿Cual es la opción aconsejada a día de hoy? o al menos ¿cual es la más sencilla?

Un Saludo

Answer (score 0):

Yo me decantaría por Nginx + uwsgi, además lo que suelo hacer es lanzar uwsgi utilizando Supervisor para el auto-arranque, restart, etc.

Dejo la config de mi web (simplificado, ya que quité la configuración de SSL para simplificar)
**NGINX config**

```
    upstream alanwagner {
     server unix:/home/alan/deploy/alanwagner/alanwagner.sock;  

   }

    server {  
     server_name www.alanwagner.es;
     listen 80;


    # Esto es para optimizar tus estáticos
    location /static {
        gzip  on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_proxied any;
        #gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

            expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

        alias /home/alan/webs/alanwagner_2018/personal_site/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    error_log /home/alan/deploy/alanwagner/tmp/logs/error.log warn;
    location / {
       # return 503;

        # auth_basic "Restricted";
        # auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        uwsgi_pass  alanwagner;
        include     /home/alan/deploy/alanwagner/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 600s;

}
```

**UWSGI PARAMS**

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/alan/webs/alanwagner_2018/personal_site
# Django's wsgi file
module          = personal_site.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
#home            = /home/alan/webs/refundair
home            = /home/alan/venvs/alanwagner

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 2
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /home/alan/deploy/alanwagner/alanwagner.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 777
#uid = www-data
#gid = www-data

# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

**Supervisor file**

```
[program:uwsgi_alanwagner]
user = alan
command = /home/alan/venvs/alanwagner/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/alan/deploy/alanwagner/uwsgi.ini
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile = /home/alan/deploy/alanwagner/logs/uwsgi/err.log
stdout_logfile = /home/alan/deploy/alanwagner/logs/uwsgi/out.log
stopsignal=INT
```